# jqgrid edit form autocomplete="off" by default, how to change to autocomplete="on"

Tags: jquery, forms, jqgrid, autocomplete, autofill

Recently my edit forms for jqgrid have not been having the nice autofill functionality that is common to Google Chrome and Firefox.  I found that the jqGrid edit forms are being rendered with each `<input>` having this property:

```
autocomplete="off"
```

In JqGrid what do I have to do in my grid definition to remove this property or set it to `autocomplete="on"`?

I do not see anything about it in the [ColModel definition](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options) or the [edit form options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing).  Any help here would be really great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe that there is anything in the [edit API](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing) to enable autofill on a field in the edit form. Though you could do it using jQuery in the event `afterShowForm` and set the autocomplete property on any of the fields that you wish. The ID's of each field is the same as the name in your column model.

```
afterShowForm : function (formid) {
    $('#name').attr('autocomplete', 'on');
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you this is the first thing I tried too after I posted.  It is successfully setting the autocomplete attribute = "on".  Unfortunately autocomplete is still not working on the form.

Comment: Maybe try setting it on the form itself too $('#FrmGrid_yourgridid').attr('autocomplete', 'on');

Comment: yeah that didn't change anything.  I think that it has something to do with the way the form is submitted.  These edit forms are submitted via ajax, and I think the browser is not prompted to save the autocomplete history unless the forms are submitted in the traditional manner...  It is just funny because the autocomplete worked for a long time with our jqGrid forms by default, and suddenly about a month ago they stopped working.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind - Regarding that "about a month ago they stopped working" - Did you just recently upgrade jqGrid? What versions?